# How to count the number of cycles between two positions in LabVIEW on myRIO

Tags: labview

I am very new to labview and recently I had been trying to make this sequence loop. 
E.g. 
myRio's starting position is ((x <0.05) && (y <=0.05) &&( z>0.9))
next while detecting myRio's position changes to  ((x<0.2) && (y <= -0.9) &&( z<=0.3)) and then back again to the starting position, it will turn validate this as one correct cycle and change the counter from 0 to 1. and loop this whole sequence again.

Would really appreciate if you could highlight how can I do these kind of sequence looping. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if what you are trying to do is to count *transitions between states*. A great design pattern for anything involving transitions between states - which covers a large part of what people generally use LabVIEW for - is a [**state machine**](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3024/en/).

The link gives an explanation but essentially what you need is:

- a While loop with a shift register
- a case structure inside the loop whose case selector is wired to the left shift register terminal
- some logic inside each case that decides what value to output to the right shift register terminal, i.e. what state to go to next.

In your case you could implement this with just two states:

**State 1:** Check position and see if we have reached the target position.

- If so go to State 2
- If not go to State 1 again

**State 2:** Check position and see if we have got back to the start position.

- If so, increment the count and go to State 1
- If not, go to State 2 again

However it would be slightly more elegant to use three states:

**State 2:** Check position and see if we have got back to the start position.

- If so, go to State 3
- If not, go to State 2 again

**State 3:** Increment the count and go to State 1.

You can use a second shift register for the counter: initialise it to 0, wire the left terminal across to the right one in States 1 and 2 (leaving the count unchanged) and increment it in State 3.

You can use an integer value or a string for the case selector, but the best practice is to use an **enum** which you save as a **typedef**. This allows you to reorder, rename, add or remove states later on without breaking existing code.